# TFS Change server port and visual studio 2012, problems

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have been using tfs with no problems on local network with port 8080. Then i decided to change the port.... why o why did i bother. I have had a terrible few hours trying to sort it. Searched goggle for fixes etc. I think i now have it working but only after reall problems, this then makes me wander and worried about how to from visual studio 2012:

1. have a local area network conenction to tfs: servername:9876
2. remote connection: domain name: domain.com:9876

both of which map to the same folders on pc/ laptop and same projects on tfs server.

This caused masses of problems, i then delete the server and re added the correct one. Deleted all cache and workspaces. But then i couldnt map to location as it existed. then couldnt create a new worksapce it said it existed even after delteing the cache. In the end i delete all again, chose a new location on pc for to pull down solutions in tfs. This worked but i am afraid if i look at the solution file in notepad the server port is 8080 still even though the server is now 9876. Based on the above 2 questions what should i do next time. Or even should i still do to make sure all is clean and tidy.

I must have this wrong as it cant be so hard to change the port nunmber of the server or even the server name its self.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS also registers your workspaces and machine names on the server. Run `tf workspaces` from the command line to figure out which and `tf workspace` to remove them. That should unblock you. Renaming your local machine (the client machine), or mapping to a different location on your local disk will unblock you.

You should use one single machine name, both locally and remote for the TFS server or map them as if they were different servers. Using both server names completely screws up the local cache, since the API will figure out that they're actually the same server because the Project Collection GUID and the Server ID match.

You could even use a line in your hosts file to be able to always use the same machine name.

I can't find the definitive  piece of documentation that tells you to use the same name for all locations, but [this blog post comes close](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ablock/archive/2009/08/24/exposing-tfs-2010-beta-2-to-the-internet.aspx). Architecturally, there are no changes between 2010 and 2012.

Comment: jessehouwing thanks for the details. I am currently looaces on the server as you advised, thanks.

I have had a quick look at the document in the link (will have to read it in more details i feel), but i am setting up a very basic tfs configuration. All i want to be able to do is: when users are in the office connect over lan and when out of the office connect over the internet..simples. I would of thought this is common place in most organisation (working in office and at home).. Surely TFS can handle this without messing in the hosts file etc. If not please help some more, thanks.

Comment: In our setup users always use the external host name to connect to TFS. That solves all issues.

Comment: Ok thanks. How's does the external name get resolved internally or is it here you alter the hosts file when in the office. If so  what's the easiest way to change the server. As last time it took me about 3 or more hours of problems. Is their any extensions to vs to make it possible. Thanks again.

Comment: We just resolve to the external IP, Dependign on your network setup that should just work. Your setup might also resolve to a different IP from your internal DNS server than from your external DNS server. Lot's of options. To change the name in TFS open the Team Foudnation Server Administration Console and update the Notification Url.

Comment: thankyou. I also downloaded side kicks for vs 2012 tfs, allows the deletion and editing of worspaces. really good. http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2012